# Warum werden "Goebbels" und "Goethe" nicht "Göbbels" und "Göthe" geschrieben?

Tags: etymology, spelling

Was ich verstanden habe, ist daß die "ae", "oe" und "ue" Buchstabenkombinationen als ein billiger Ersatz für ä, ö und ü dienen, wenn die Umlaute nicht zur Verfügung stehen. Diese Buchstabenkombination findet man sonst normalerweise nicht in der deutschen Sprache.

Warum werden die Namen von zwei bekannteren Deutschen mit "oe" geschrieben? Sind es ausländische Namen?

Comment: Gute Beispiel, und es sieht aus, das "Goering" ist auch oft als "Göring" geschrieben, dann ersetze ich er mit Goethe.

Comment: @CarstenS autsch, die duplicate question ist englisch... (retracted)

Comment: @Stephie, ach Regeln. Es versteht doch jeder Englisch. (Ich habe aber allgemein nicht genau geprüft, ob das eine Doublette ist.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Namen sind eben Namen - Sie gehören spätestens seit dem 18. Jahrhundert (manche sehr viel früher, bis zu 600 Jahre vorher) zu einer Famile und haben sich durch die Jahrhunderte auch kaum in der Schreibweise geändert, auf jeden Fall nicht so stark wie der Rest der deutschen Sprache.

Spätestens seit ein Familienname zur speziellen Identifikation einer Person auch gegenüber der Obrigkeit gebraucht wurde (ca. 1870), durfte er nicht mehr ohne sehr triftigen Grund geändert werden. So haben sich viele alte Schreibweisen und teilweise auch Begriffe in den Familiennamen erhalten, die die offizielle Sprache schon lange abgelegt hat.

Im Übrigen halte ich deine Ansicht, die Umschreibung der deutschen Umlaute mit ae, ue und oe als "billigen Ersatz" zu sehen, für falsch. An sich ist es tatsächlich genau andersrum. Irgendeine Art Wertung ist hier sicher fehl am Platz.

Answer (score 4):

Umlaute wurden ursprünglich als "oe", "ae" und "ue" geschrieben. Später wurde das "e" über den Buchstaben gestellt, was noch später zu zwei Strichen bzw. Punkten vereinfacht wurde. (Siehe https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%96)

Die Namen Goebbels und Goethe wurden gebildet, als die Umlaute noch mit "oe" geschrieben wurden. Personen- und Ortsnamen behalten gewöhnlich die Schreibung, die sie zu der Zeit hatten, als die Namen in Verzeichnissen wie Geburtsurkunden, Ausweisdokumenten, Landkarten und ähnlichem verschriftlicht wurden. Deshalb konservieren Namen eine altertümliche Schreibung.

Der Familienname von Johann Wolfgang Goethe wurde ursprünglich "Göthe" geschrieben. Einer seiner Vorfahren änderte die Schreibung des Namens zu Goethe. (Siehe https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johann_Wolfgang_von_Goethe) Tatsächlich wurde der Name aber in einigen der zu Goethes Lebzeiten veröffentlichten Werke auch "Göthe" geschrieben.

Offenbar war die Verschriftlichung der Lautung damals im Übergang und noch nicht gefestigt. Die ersten Bemühungen um eine Vereinheitlichung der deutschen Orthografie wurden Mitte des 19. Jahrhunderts unternommen, also lang nach Goethes Tod. 1879 und 1880 wurden die ersten offiziellen Regelbücher veröffentlicht (in Preußen und Bayern, mit unterschiedlichen Regeln).

Andere bekannte altertümliche Namensschreibungen sind Calw (gesprochen "kalf") und Duisburg (gesprochen Düsburg). The orhtography of family names can differ by dialectal region, as can be seen on this map of the name Maier/Mayer/Meier/Meyer: http://images.zeit.de/lebensart/2011-04/d-karte-15/d-karte-15-thickbox.jpg

Comment: Sehr gut! Folgende Aussage finde ich allerdings verwirrend, da sie selbst wissen, dass Goethes Großvater eigentlich Göthe hieß: *Die Namen Goebbels und Goethe wurden gebildet, als die Umlaute noch mit "oe" geschrieben wurden*.

Comment: Ja, das widerspricht sich. Man müsste da mehr recherchieren, aber dazu fehlt mir die Zeit und Möglichkeit.

Comment: Ich würde nicht ausschließen, dass spätestens seit Goethes Zeiten, das *oe* als gehobener empfunden wird.